# Android convert image to video using mediacodec and Opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I started from : http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/, EncodeAndMuxTest example. There frames are generated using opengl. I changed the generateSurfaceFrame() method as I will show:

```
private void generateSurfaceFrame(int frameIndex) 
{
   final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];
   GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
   if (textureHandle[0] != 0) 
   {
        // decode image to bitmap
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("PathToMyImage.jpg");

        GLES20.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,                    
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

The problem is that all I get is a video with black background, I don't know if I load image correctly, or how to draw the image using Opengl.
I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?